# Cómo asignar un atributo data desde un componente a otro en React

Tags: reactjs, data, component

Soy nuevo en React y estoy comenzando a aprender cómo hacer componentes funcionales, hice una página hasta ahora y le implementé un Dark Mode que funciona perfecto, pero quería hacer que la funcionalidad de ese Dark Mode sea un componente para poder importarlo a todas las páginas que haga. Este es el código del DarkMode:

```
import React from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import "../pages/login.css";
import { IoSunnyOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { IoMoonOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import useLocalStorage from "use-local-storage";

const DarkMode = () => {

    const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage("theme" ? "dark" : "light");

     const switchTheme = () => {
          const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
          setTheme(newTheme);
     };

     return (
          <Fragment>
               <div className='tema-wrap' onClick={switchTheme}>
                    {theme === "light" ? (<IoMoonOutline className='icon-theme moon' />) : (<IoSunnyOutline className='icon-theme sun' />)}
               </div>
          </Fragment>
     );
};

export default DarkMode;
```

La variable "theme" la coloco dinámicamente en el data-attribute del contenedor padre de mi página, eso funcionaba bien cuando tenía la función del modo oscuro en el mismo archivo, pero ahora que lo separé en un componente, la consola del navegador me dice que 'theme' no está definido, y es que importo el componente creado DarkMode, pero no consigo que el atributo que le asigno al data-attribute lo reconozca

Line 42:46:  'theme' is not defined  no-undef

```
<div className="content" data-theme={theme}>
```

¿Qué debería hacer en este caso?

Comment: Hay al menos 3 cosas que me llaman la atención de tu código. **1.** No estás llamando a tu componente `DarkMode`  de esta manera: `<DarkMode />`. En vez de eso lo hace con un `<div>` el cual ni siquiera tiene etiqueta de cierre **2.** No estoy seguro, pero creo que no se puede poner como nombre de propiedad algo que tenga guiones, por lo tanto `data-theme` no me parece un buen nombre **3.** Dentro del componente `DarkMode` no estás recibiendo las props, deberías hacerlo así `const DarkMode = (props)` y luego llamar a tu variable así `props.theme`. Creo que deberías solucionar esos 3 problemas.

Comment: El componente lo llamo en otra parte del código, no lo mostré porque no es relevante para este caso, el div es un contenedor de toda la página, envuelve toda la interfaz, simplemente muestro la primera línea de ese div porque es donde se encuentra el data-attribute, el cual lleva un guión porque así es la sintaxis. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Ok, entonces eso aclararía los puntos 1 y 2 que te mencioné. Con respecto al punto 3, recién ahora entiendo que en realidad estás usando la librería [use-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-local-storage). Según su documentación, tienes que darle una `key` y un valor inicial. Y creo que no lo estás inicializando correctamente, porque estás usando un operador ternario que no está validando nada: `"theme" ? "dark" : "light"`. ¿Por qué no ponerle un valor inicial parecido a este `useLocalStorage("theme", "light")`? Así por defecto es "light" y después se lo vas cambiando.